# ontouch in android-draw rectangle

Tags: android, canvas, drawrect, touch-event

in my application on touch event i want to drawrectangle-i tried this.butnot getting exactly how to draw.please help me.
i want to draw rectangle on points where is touched.
how can i use getX() and getY() in drawRect() method?
below is code-

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
             if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                                int X=event.getX(); int Y=event.getY();
                    Paint paint = new Paint();
                    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
                    paint.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.Yellow)) ;
                    paint.setAlpha(opacity);
                               Canvas canvas1 = new Canvas(mutableimage1);
                          canvas1.drawRect(2.5f,2.5f,2.5f,2.5f, paint);
                                 }
              }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't instantiate a new object in the onTouch method : `canvas1 = new Canvas(...)`
It will cause freezes and lags. Create this canvas once for good at the creation of your view.

Be carefull I think your `drawRect()` call won't draw what you need : 
you are drawing a rect with x=2.5 y = 2.5 width=2.5 height=2.5

I assume you need to position your rect according to the touch position :

```
//set the x and y pos according to the touch point
// by removing half the size of the rect we center it on this point ;)
canvas1.drawRect( X-1.25f, Y-1.25f, 2.5F, 2.5f, paint );
```

Otherwise that's quite correct, but  be aware that you are drawing on a mutable bitmap ("mutableimage1") that won't necessary be displayed.

You probably want to add the display in the `onDraw(Canvas viewCanvas)` method of your view.
using :

`viewCanvas.drawBitmap(mutableimage1, 0,0, aPreviouslyCreatedPaint);`

Comment: actully i'm trying to draw rectangle on image.and when i trird for circle its working.but rectangle is not displaying

Comment: Ok you probably need to compare your code for the rectangle and the circle ? what's the difference that can cause the rectangle not to be drawn. Did I help you so far ?